# How below custommalloc program is behaving in different manner

Tags: c, linux, malloc

I am trying to write a custom malloc and I have taken reference from this github repo

https://github.com/FallAngel1337/mymalloc

I am trying to make a single linked list of allocated nodes using sbrk as below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct metadata
{
    size_t size;
    unsigned char magic;
    struct metadata *next;
};

struct metadata *head = NULL;

void *mymalloc(size_t size);
void myfree(void *ptr);


void *mymalloc(size_t size)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;
    struct metadata *block = NULL;
    block = sbrk(0);
    size_t fsize = sizeof(block) + size;
    sbrk(fsize);

    block->next = NULL;
    block->size = size - sizeof(struct metadata);
    block->magic = 1;

    if(NULL == head)
    {
        head = block;
        printf("%d: %p\n", __LINE__, block->next);
    }
    else
    {
        struct metadata *tmp;
        printf("%d: %p %p\n", __LINE__, tmp->next, head->next);
        tmp = head;
        while(NULL != tmp->next)
        {
            printf("%d: %p\n", __LINE__, tmp->next);
            //if(head)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = block;
    }
    return (block+1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int *arr, *prr;
    arr = mymalloc(4);
    prr = mymalloc(6);
    if(NULL != arr)
    {
        arr[0] = 1;
        arr[1] = 2;
        arr[2] = 3;
        printf("arr: %d %d %d\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
    }
    if(NULL != prr)
    {
        prr[0] = 4;
        prr[1] = 5;
        prr[2] = 6;
        printf("prr: %d %d %d\n", prr[0], prr[1], prr[2]);
    }
    //myfree(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

(ignore that it doesn't have myfree implemented yet.) Above code works with below commands,

```
gcc -g3 -o malloctest malloctest.c
❯ ./malloctest1
36: (nil)
41: 0xc35f415e415d415c (nil)
arr: 1 2 3
prr: 4 5 6
```

But when I remove few prints as below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct metadata
{
    size_t size;
    unsigned char magic;
    struct metadata *next;
};

struct metadata *head = NULL;

void *mymalloc(size_t size);
void myfree(void *ptr);


void *mymalloc(size_t size)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;
    struct metadata *block = NULL;
    block = sbrk(0);
    size_t fsize = sizeof(block) + size;
    sbrk(fsize);

    block->next = NULL;
    block->size = size - sizeof(struct metadata);
    block->magic = 1;

    if(NULL == head)
    {
        head = block;
    }
    else
    {
        struct metadata *tmp;
        tmp = head;
        while(NULL != tmp->next)
        {
            printf("%p %p\n", tmp->next, NULL);
            //if(head)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = block;
    }
    return (block+1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int *arr, *prr;
    arr = mymalloc(4);
    prr = mymalloc(6);
    if(NULL != arr)
    {
        arr[0] = 1;
        arr[1] = 2;
        arr[2] = 3;
        printf("arr: %d %d %d\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
    }
    if(NULL != prr)
    {
        prr[0] = 4;
        prr[1] = 5;
        prr[2] = 6;
        printf("prr: %d %d %d\n", prr[0], prr[1], prr[2]);
    }
    //myfree(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

now running this code give me segmentation fault.

```
❯ gcc -g3 -o malloctest1 malloctest1.c
❯ ./malloctest
0x1ffffffff (nil)
[1]    45258 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./malloctest1
```

Can anyone point out where is the mistake. Checking the diff

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV2fE.png)

tried gdb debugger and saw head = block doesn't make head->next to NULL,instead it prints 0x1ffffffff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have UB here as you do not allocate enough memory and you write outside the allocated memory

It should be:

```
int main(void)
{
    int *arr, *prr;
    arr = mymalloc(3 * sizeof(*arr));
    prr = mymalloc(3 * sizeof(*ptr));
   
    /* .... */
```

Note: It is better if you use ***objects*** not *types* in `sizeof`.